# Where clause in a query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a query using SQLite in Android Studio but I am having big trouble with it.
I am trying to `select * from Student.db where name = Mike`

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
package com.example.lyubo.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by LYUBO on 2017/08/07.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }



    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = Mike",null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that the problem is within my query. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: You need to quote for string comparison: ... = 'Mike'

Comment: OMG!! I just wasted 2 hours.
Thank you so much for this Sir. Problem solved!

Comment: if I want to view it based on user's input would I just replace the Mike part and write like this:

Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = " +  mainAct.editName.getText().toString() ,null);

Comment: Try, and you'll fail... again: you need to use the quotation marks around the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `res.moveToFirst()`
Why?
Basically cursor has no idea where to go or locate itself(don't know how to put it in actual words) so you need to place it inside the **list** in order to perform DB queries.

Try trimming the string to make sure there is no extra white space:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME.trim()+" WHERE "+COL_2.trim()+" = Mike" , null);
```

Comment: Thank you. 
if I want to view it based on user's input would I just replace the Mike part and write like this: Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = " + "mainAct.editName.getText().toString()" ,null);

Comment: Don't forget to trim after `toString()`

Comment: And kindly mark it as answered to help others! Thanks!